# Can't send mail from Windows Phone (Postfix server)

Tags: ssl, postfix, dovecot, tls

**Some background:**

I have a Dovecot/Postfix setup to handle email for a few domains. We have imap and smtp setup on various devices (Macs, iPhones, PCs, etc) and it works no problem.

I've recently bought a Windows Phone and I'm trying to setup the mail account on there. I've got the imap part working great but for some reason it won't send mail.

**mail.log with debug_peer_list**

I've put this on pastebin because its quite long:

http://pastebin.com/KdvMDxTL

**dovecot.log with verbose_ssl**

```
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before/accept initialization [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before/accept initialization [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 read client hello A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write server hello A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write certificate A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write server done A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 flush data [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3 read client certificate A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3 read client certificate A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 read client key exchange A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 read finished A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write change cipher spec A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write finished A [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 flush data [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:50 imap-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully [109.151.23.129]
Apr 14 22:43:51 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<pixelfolio>, method=PLAIN, rip=109.151.23.129, lip=94.23.254.175, mpid=24390, TLS
Apr 14 22:43:53 imap(pixelfolio): Info: Disconnected: Logged out bytes=9/331
Apr 14 22:43:53 imap-login: Warning: SSL alert: where=0x4008, ret=256: warning close notify [109.151.23.129]
```

**postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_list = 109.151.23.129
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 50240000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = ks383809.kimsufi.com, localhost.kimsufi.com, localhost
myhostname = ks383809.kimsufi.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891,inet:localhost:8892
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891,inet:localhost:8892
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = domz.co.uk ruck.in vjgary.co.uk scriptees.co.uk pixelfolio.co.uk filmtees.co.uk nbsbar.co.uk
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/alias_maps
```

**doveconf -n**

```
# 2.0.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 x86_64 Ubuntu 11.10 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = mbox:~/mail/:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
verbose_ssl = yes
```

Any suggestions or help greatly appreciated. I've been pulling my hair out with this for hours!

**EDIT**

This seems to be my exact problem, but I already have broken_sasl set to yes and the 'login' auth mechanism added?

http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-898610-start-0.html

Answer (score 2):

It's PLAIN, not LOGIN, that it's trying to authenticate with.

The following option comes to mind:

```
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
```

You may want to add additional things besides just plain to that.